# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence with Maps APIv2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to make an Android app that displays a map and zooms in on your current location (currently just trying to get the zoom to work), and I have been getting for this error for the last 3 days:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
//                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(8));
        }
    });
}
```

in my MainActivity.java and in the layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the relevant components from the manifest:

```
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
    android:uiOptions="">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXX" />
```

Thanks for any thoughts you might have. Most suggestions thus far seem to indicate some problem with the API key - as a result I have changed the API key multiple times from the Google API console, regenerated my debug.keystore and regenerated the key to no avail.

**Update:** Here's my build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debug {
        }

        release {
        }
        runProguard false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
        androidTest.setRoot('androidTest')
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:3.+'
}
```

Comment: Have you added google_play_service_lib in your project?

Comment: I suggest please follow this tutorial:[http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/]

Comment: I added it via a dependency in the build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this problem since about the same moment you started getting it. Until now I still can't explain it or solve it, but I have found that if you do NOT setmyLocationEnable(true); the map will load properly. This is still a problem for me since I need to see my location, but I hope it will help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project go into > properties > java build path > select order and export tab
check in all libraries/ required folder needed for project click ok button build the project and compile it

hope it will work for you

it worked for me may be it will work for you too :)

Comment: I'm using Android Studio - not Eclipse, so it doesn't look like I can really change the libraries that way - I've added the build.gradle which includes google play services as a dependency. Thanks for the suggestion though.